# SQL - Self join for latest row

Tags: sql

Here's the table:

```
    id -           date               - attempts
    --------------------------------------------
    1  -  2012-12-11 14:52:06.143     - success
    2  -  2012-12-11 15:51:52.320     - whatever
    3  -  2012-12-11 12:51:52.321     - success
    4  -  2012-12-11 12:51:52.312     - whatever 
    5  -  2012-12-11 14:51:52.320     - fail
```

I am trying to get the latest 'fail' and the latest 'success' rows and then, of the two, see if the latest one was a failure (there can be success rows later than fail rows).

I can't just select the latest row, as it might be other than 'success' or 'fail'.

Comment: `ORDER BY` + `attempts IN ('fail', 'success')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner query will identify the record with the latest date where the attempt is either success or failure, the outer query combines with the results of inner query to identify failure records.

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    myTable a
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT MAX(date) AS `date` FROM myTable
        WHERE attempts IN ('success', 'fail')
    ) b
    ON a.date = b.date
WHERE
    a.attempts = 'fail'
```

Comment: (added the `date` alias so the ON clause succeeds)

Comment: Ah! Thank you. I missed that one.

Comment: ummm, 'record count: 0' for me on that fiddle

Comment: @mcalex Yes, because the greatest timestamp 12:51:52.321  is `success`, not `fail`.

Comment: Thank you very much to all. Vikdor - great answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
  Select s.id successId, s.date latestSuccess, 
         f.id failId, f.date latestFail, 
         case When s.date > f.Date 
              Then 'Success' Else 'Fail' End Last
  From myTable s full join mytable f
     On s.attempts = 'success'
        And s.date - (Select Max(date) From myTable
                    Where attempts = 'success')
        And f.attempts = 'fail'
        And f.date - (Select Max(date) From myTable
                      Where attempts = 'fail')
```